# Oracle SQL - How to query most recently changed data

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Im currently testing a REST service that I dont know wich database changes are made when using. I would like to be able to make a REST call and then inspect the Oracle Database using for example Oracle SQL Developer to filter out only the changes made over that last x minuts?

Is this possible?

Comment: Does the table in question have a column for timestamp?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: *"to filter out only the changes made over that last x minuts"*: So you *only* want to the data from the last x minutes?  Or you want to *exclude* the data from the last x minutes?

Comment: I dont know wich tables are affected. I would like to list all affected tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add two columns to all your tables: `date_created` and `date_updated` and populate them on INSERT/UPDATE from the code? This way you can easily keep track of all changes in database and you don't depend on specific RDBMS (in your case - Oracle)

Comment: I dont have that sort of permission to change anything in the DB